# RXJava/RXAndroid - Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, rx-android

When you received an error with this message

rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError

but your subscription is already handling onError

```
MyMethodThatRetunsAnObservable(string)
        .subscribe(
            response -> handleResponse(response),
            throwable -> handleError(throwable));
```

In case that is caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Note that onError notifications will cut ahead of onNext notifications on the emission thread if Scheduler is truly asynchronous. So it's needed to specify the UI Thread in which we are going to observe

```
public static void shortToast(String msg) {
    Observable.just(msg)
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(message -> {
                Toast.makeText(App.getInstance(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
}
```

Comment: where is a question?

Comment: It's just what to do when you received that error using rxjava/rxAndroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you got the error. You should call `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` instead of `observerOn`. The show log function was called before the `observerOn` and called in the `onSubcribe` method.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am going to update the answer. thanks